# How can conan help CMake find location of DLLs?

Tags: c++, cmake, conan

I have a project that creates a shared library. This project uses conan to manage its dependencies, one of them being OpenCV. Due to corporate policy we don't use [opencv_world](http://www.programmerfish.com/should-you-be-using-opencv-world-module/) and always use shared libraries, so conan installs hundreds of `.lib` and `.dll` files.

The project I'm developing includes a number of executables to run tests - unit, integration, profile, etc, but those tests need to have the path to the dll of the dependencies. My question is, how to manage these paths?

Is there a way to automagically pass the location of the files from conan to cmake?

Should I find the location of the files by hand and pass them manually to CMake?

Comment: Are you currently already using the [CMake generator](https://docs.conan.io/en/latest/integrations/build_system/cmake/cmake_generator.html#targets-approach)?

Comment: Yes but don't see how it will give me the path to the DLLs.

Comment: The library path(s) should be a property of the generated target, as the compiler needs those paths as well. You can then extract the path with `get_target_property`. I do not have a Conan installation on hand to test, unfortunately.

Comment: I need to copy the DLLs themselves to the same folder where my unit tests reside otherwise they won't run, as the question says.

Comment: unit tests loading external dll-s are not unit tests. You should utilize a dependency injection. Integration/functional test are running everything as a whole and they are loading dependencies (dlls).

Comment: Why aren't they unit tests? The code they test depends on OpenCV. Either way I need to copy those DLLs to the executable's directory, no matter the type of test.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is what I did:

1) Change the conan project generator to [virtualrunenv](https://docs.conan.io/en/latest/mastering/virtualenv.html#virtualrunenv-generator) and install packages as documented.

2) Start the [developer prompt](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/framework/tools/developer-command-prompt-for-vs), or execute the script it runs on startup from any command line window.

3) Open the CMake project from Visual Studio.

4) Run tests. All libraries are now available.

Answer (score 0):

You must successfully find opencv, so you can get related cached cmake variables. Get opencv's dll paths from one of those variables ( by scripting in your cmake files), and wrote it to a .bat (windows) or .sh (linux/mac) file. That shell script file should add dll paths to PATH variable temporaily, then do your unittest. Not sure if this is relied on conan since I never use that.